# Multiple image upload to rails - updating multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I am attempting to implement multiple file upload functionality into my Rails app using the 'jquery-fileupload-rails' and 'carrierwave' gems.

The app basically has projects that have multiple steps, and each step can have multiple images.

I am attempting to upload images while in a form for updating a particular step.  When I attempt to upload an image, nothing seems to happen.  if you can help shed some light, I would be eternally grateful!  Thanks in advance.

**routes.rb:**

```
Build::Application.routes.draw do

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  resources :projects do
    resources :steps
    match "steps/:id" => "steps#number", :as => :number
  end

  resources :images

  root :to => 'projects#index'

end
```

**step.rb:**

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :number

    attr_accessible :description, :name, :number, :project_id, :images_attributes
    belongs_to :project
    has_many :images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => :true

end
```

**image.rb:**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :step_id, :file, :caption, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  belongs_to :step
  belongs_to :project

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

end
```

**file_uploader.rb:**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
     "/assets/"
     # "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [420,315]
  end


end
```

**views/steps/edit.html.erb:**

```
<div class="row span12">
  <div class="row">

<%= render 'step_form' %>

</div>
</div>
```

**views/steps/_step_form.html.erb (this handles updating the image model via a partial as indicated below):**

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@project, @step], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do%>

....
      <div class = "imageGalleryButtons">

          <span class="btn btn-mini fileinput-button">
            <i class = "icon-plus"></i>
            Add Photo
            <%= render :partial => 'images/upload_form', :locals => {:form => f} %>
          </span>
          <%= link_to 'Reorder Photos', '#', :class=> "btn btn-mini" %>
          <!--<button class="btn btn-large">Reorder Photos</button>-->
    </div>

  <div class = "clear"></div> 

</div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**views/images/_upload_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form.fields_for :images, :html => {:multipart => true} do |image_form| %>   
   <%= image_form.file_field :file, :multiple=>true%>
<% end %>
```

**application.js:**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree 
//= require js-routes
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` file ?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the application.js file contents.

Comment: Have you created javascript , related to the multiple file upload ? There is a nice [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) on the topic . It'll be very helpful in your case .

Comment: I have been following that tutorial as well as the original carrierwave one (for single-file uploads).  Unfortunately, it's still not working.  I think it might have to do with the way I have set up my models since they aren't nested like in his example.